# Reading from location 0000000000000000 in C program

Tags: c, crash

I have a 10k lines of code C program that sometimes crashes.
I cannot replicate that crash. All I can do is to wait for it to happen and then try to debug it.

This is what I get from drmingw

> EXCEPTION PID=18632 TID=10612 ExceptionCode=0xc0000005 dwFirstChance=0

> mypgr.exe caused an Access Violation at location 0000000000402CB2 in
> module mypgr.exe Reading from location 0000000000000000.
>
> AddrPC           Params
> 0000000000402CB2 0000000000A862D0 0000000000000003 00000000035BE380  mypgr.exe!manage_ids  [C:/Users/mn/Documents/code blocks/zbr/common.c @ 440]

```
if(unique_id[i]->idd[32] != 0) 
    log_errors_to_file("xd2");

dbg_str_len = 0;

for(int xd = 0;xd < 32;xd++) { //  ERROR IN THIS LOOP
    if(ant_tb[j][k]->idd[xd] == 0) 
        break;
    dbg_str_len++;
};

if(dbg_str_len != 32) 
    log_errors_to_file("xd3");

if(ant_tb[j][k]->idd[32] != 0) 
    log_errors_to_file("xd4");
```

I know this code does not make any sense but I tried many strange things to replicate the crash.
Anyway my debugger shows that below line is causing the problem

> for(int xd = 0;xd < 32;xd++){if(ant_tb[j][k]->idd[xd] == 0) break;dbg_str_len++;};

But why? Is it possible to crash the app by just reading?

Comment: Zero is a null pointer. You're trying to dereference a null pointer. Always check your pointers before you use them!

Comment: Check for `ant_tb[j][k] == NULL`

Comment: Also for easier debugging, don't try to cram as much as you can onto single lines. One statement per line helps with making it easier to debug, making it easier to read and understand, and also making it easier to maintain.

Comment: "Is it possible to crash the app by just reading?" Yes, if you are trying to read from memory that you don't have permission to access. Not just address `0` but any memory where you are not allowed.  (Otherwise you could snoop).

Comment: You need to start at the crash and work backwards.  Look at the stack, examine the values of your all your variables and check every dereference along the way.  You might be running off the end of your buffer, or you might have a legit null access.  If your program is multi-threaded, there could be synchronization mistakes.  Some other part of the program could be overwriting memory by accident.  Your code might be assuming something about the data that is different to the design.  Many things can cause a crash.  Start by eliminating possibilities and exploring theories.

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` is great at debugging these problems.

Comment: That code has bad style and low quality, you should write some unit-tests to lock down the functionality, and then do refactoring and clean up the code base. After that you can start hunting bugs with more understanding and focus. Clean code really helps with maintenance and troubleshooting.

Comment: This (very sloppily written) code with no context doesn't say anything. All you know is that the crash happened there - you don't know the location of the bug. However you know the cause - dereferencing some pointer pointing at NULL. Also with code looking this bad, you are almost certainly just seeing the top of the iceberg. Expect multiple other more or less dormant bugs all over the place.

Comment: Btw how does `ant_tb[j][k]->idd[32]` make sense given that you iterate over indices 0 to 31? Are you sure this isn't a plain old out-of-bounds bug?

Comment: I edited the code. Show which statement in the loop that causes it